# SQL Server 2019 backup from EC2 windows instance directly to S3

Tags: sql-server, windows, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, backup

I tried to take backup from my EC2 instance where I have SQL Server  installed using T-SQL script but it is working with 2022 server but not with SQL Server 2019.

How can I take backup from a SQL Server 2019?

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL \[s3://bucketname.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket\] WITH IDENTITY = 'name' ,SECRET = 'AKYT:JK\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*JV';

BACKUP DATABASE \[DB_Name\] 
TO URL = 's3://bucketname.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/\<DB_Name\>.BAK' 
WITH COMPRESSION
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it is not working with 2019? Does it throw an error?

Comment: _Backup and restore to S3-compatible storage was introduced in SQL Server 2022 (16.x), see SQL Server backup and restore with S3-compatible object storage._ REF: [BACKUP (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql). You'll probably need to do this manually, i.e.: backup to a local ephemeral drive and then use `aws s3 mv` to move it to S3 storage.